# displaying a div only on tumblr blog homepage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr

I have a fairly novice understanding of CSS and HTML, and I'm trying to do something that I think should be relatively simple (in a custom tumblr theme I'm creating), but I can't find a straightforward answer. I have a feeling there might be a super easy way to do what I want in JavaScript.

I'd like to display a `DIV` *only* on the main index page (i.e. homepage) of the tumblr blog.  It seems the documentation tumblr provides allows you to do this to some extent (through the {Block:IndexPage} variable), but the problem is the code within this element displays on *all* index pages (i.e. instead of just showing up at the root level on /page/1, it will show up on subsequent "index" pages like /page/2, etc.

Here's the code I have, which successfully does not show the div on permalink pages:

```
{block:IndexPage}
    <div class="mid2">
        <div class="midLeft2">  
            <p>test</p>
        </div>   
    </div>
{/block:IndexPage}
```

Any ideas? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: There is a big chance this has nothing to do with javascript, but the templating system tumblr uses.

Comment: @SoonDead right, so the {Block:IndexPage} variable is clearly limited here, but since all of this is ultimately just using HTML, I'm thinking there has to be a way to override this behavior through means I'm unfamiliar with? Like maybe have the page check somehow its location and only display the div if it's the homepage?

Comment: I'm sure there is a better solution but you can always write a javascript that makes the element "display: block" when the location.href is the index page. That is a sort of last resort solution but I can help you write it.

Comment: @SoonDead Thank you so much for offering to help. One of my friends who knows javascript was able to come up with a solution based on your suggestion. I truly appreciate your offer to help write the script!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up killing off the {Block:IndexPage} tag altogether and changing the original div callout to this:

```
<div id="splashbox" class="mid2" style="display:none">
```

Followed by this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=showsplashbox();
function showsplashbox() {
   //alert('location identified as ' + location.href);
   if (location.href == 'http://site.tumblr.com/' || location.href == 'http://site.tumblr.com') {
           //alert('location match, show the block');
           document.getElementById('splashbox').style.display='block';
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `if( {CurrentPage} == 1 ) {` does the same thing.

Comment: There is a possibly better way to do this using CSS (no JavaScript). See my answer below.

Comment: I'm very late to the party, as I am trying to get this to work on a clients tumblr now, but why is there an or statement for two conditions that are the same? Is this just an example and a way of showing that you could write a different url to also hide the element on a different page. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

This will work:

```
{block:IndexPage}
  <div id="index"
    {block:SearchPage}style="display: none;"{/block:SearchPage}
    {block:TagPage}style="display: none;"{/block:TagPage}>
    This is displayed only on the index page.
  </div>
{/block:IndexPage}
```

More info: http://ejdraper.com/post/280968117/advanced-tumblr-customization

Comment: This works perfectly for me, even on `/post/asdf` pages.

Answer (score 2):

I was was looking to show code on post pages, but not on the index, search, etc page (i.e. pages with multiple posts.  Thanks to the above, I figured out how to do it and wanted to share in case it helps somebody else.

```
<div id="splashbox" style="display:none">
      This is the content I wanted to show on the post pages only.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=showsplashbox();
function showsplashbox() {
   //alert('location identified as ' + location.href);
   if (self.location.href.indexOf("post") > -1 )  {
           document.getElementById('splashbox').style.display='block';
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it just with CSS.

```
#box{
  display:none;
}

.page1 #box{
  display:block;
}
```

---

```
<body class="page{CurrentPage}">
  <div id="box">
    Only displayed in first page.
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`display:none` will hide it but thats, a hidden element can still mess with your layout.

We could use the comment code* to turn the div into a comment that wont mess with anything.

```
*<!-- comment -->
```

ex.

```
{block:IndexPage}
{block:SearchPage}<!--{/block:SearchPage}
{block:TagPage}<!--{/block:TagPage}


<div style="width:400px; heigth:200px">
blah blah
</div>   



{block:SearchPage}-->{/block:SearchPage}
{block:TagPage}-->{/block:TagPage}
{/block:IndexPage}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `{block:IndexPage}` block, as you have discovered, is for all index pages. To target only the first page you can use `{block:Post1}` inline or `{CurrentPage}` in script. `{block:Post1}` will display only on the page with the first post, which achieves what you want. The `<div>` can then be styled to put it wherever you want.

```html
{block:Post1}
<div class="mid2">
    <div class="midLeft2">  
        <p>test</p>
    </div>   
</div>
{/block:Post1}
```

Or:

```html
<script>
if( {CurrentPage} == 1 ) {
    //display div
};
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for this. it doesn't quite work, because {block:Post1} isn't a variable that tumblr recognizes, but the solution my friend came up with isn't too far from this. The resolution was to check for the index page using location.href and use a display:block if the href was the index, otherwise do display:none. I truly appreciate your willingness to assist though, thanks!!

Comment: @soobes I use it on my theme. Search http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes for "block:post[".

Comment: I see what you mean, but this code wasn't rendering quite right when I tried it earlier because I'm not trying to target the div towards only post 1, but rather to the index, regardless of post number or chronology. Here's what my friend came up with (answer below).

Comment: @soobes Post 1 is always and only on page 1, the index page.

Comment: @soobes: I found this page because I needed the same thing, and I don't want to use JS because I don't want any divs "popping". This works, but the trick is the {block:Post1} block has to occur within the block {block:Posts}, which might have been why it wasn't working for you. So it doesn't necessarily need to be IN post 1, but it wil be in the same parent container.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by using div:not() operator.

The HTML Markup will be

```
{block:IndexPage}
<div id="banner">
   <div class="banner_{CurrentPage}">
      This Content will appear in only on home page
   </div>
</div>
{/block:IndexPage}
```

Now add this CSS to

```
#banner div:not(.banner_1)
{
   display:none;
}
{block:SearchPage}
    #banner
    {
       display:none;
    }
{/block:SearchPage}
{block:TagPage}
    #banner
    {
       display:none;
    }
{/block:TagPage}
```

The background: `{CurrentPage}` is a Tumblr theme variable which returns the page number of index pages (like 1, 2, 3, ...). Thus the home of any Tumblr blog is page number "1". Now I have defined the class of a div with this page number concatenated with a string "banner_" (Class can not be numeric. WTF why?) - making the class name "banner_1" on homepage. Next, in CSS, I have added `display:none` property to `:not` selector of that `banner_1` class div. Thus excluding div with `banner_1` class, all other div in under `#banner` div will disappear. Additionally, div with id `#banner` is hidden in search and tag pages.

Note: `<div id="#banner" >` is required. Without this, `:not` will hide all divs in the html.

---

Warning: IE users (is there anyone left?) need to change their habit. This is only supported in FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera.

I have implemented this in http://theteazone.tumblr.com/ The Big Banner (Tea is a culture) is absent in http://theteazone.tumblr.com/page/2

Comment: Now supported in IE 9 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
{block:IndexPage}

<script>
   if( {CurrentPage} != 1 ) {document.write("<!--");};
</script>

<div id="banners">
   blablabla
</div> --> 

{/block:IndexPage}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use this tag: `{block:HomePage}`.

This block renders, as its name implies, on the home page only (ie not on search pages, tag pages etc).

References:
https://www.tumblr.com/docs/fr/custom_themes