# Hide homepage feed on tumblr blog

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr

I recently found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9043594/1388140) to a question similar to mine.

Is there any way to do the opposite of this? I want to display posts everywhere EXCEPT for the homepage. I tried to reverse this code and use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=showsplashbox();
function showsplashbox() {
    //alert('location identified as ' + location.href);
if (location.href == 'http://site.tumblr.com/' || location.href == 'http://site.tumblr.com') {
    //alert('location match, show the block');
document.getElementById('splashbox').style.display='none';
    }
}
</script>
```

and then

```
<div id="splashbox" style="display:none">
```

But it doesn't seem to work.  I uncommented the alerts and everything matches up correctly, but for some reason the style isn't applied.

I have also tried the following to no avail:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      if (location.href == 'http://site.tumblr.com/' || location.href == 'http://site.tumblr.com') {
            $('#splashbox').hide();
      } else {
            $('#splashbox').show();
      }
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `style="display:none"` from your div tag.  The splashbox will be starting out hidden on every page already, but your JavaScript expects it to start shown, and then it will hide it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide splash screen on home page. And want to show every where on other pages.

```
<div id="splashbox" style="display:block"></div>
```

This will shown every where. And your script will hide it on home page.